# Restore initial package state

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, restore

How can I make that Ubuntu (apt/dpkg) restore the state of installed packages
to the state that should be just after installation. I know that there are two types of installation: "rich" and "poor". I mean it would uninstall additional packages I had installed and install basic packages I had removed.

Comment: It depends on your release. `lsb_release -sd` please.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, I know it's old, I think of upgrading

Comment: I can you only give an hint.  `cat /var/log/installer/status | grep Pack`